# JRecord - Formatting file transferred from Mainframe

Tags: ftp, eclipse-rcp, cobol, apache-commons-net, jrecord

I am trying to display a mainframe file in a eclipse RCP application using [JRecord](http://jrecord.sourceforge.net/) library.I already have the COBOL copybook as a text file. 
to accomplish that,

1. I am transferring the file from mainframe to my desktop through
   apache commons net FTPClient API
2. Now I have a text file
3. I am removing the newline and carriage return characters
4. then I read it via ., a CobolIoProvider and convert it into a ArrayList of type AbstractLine

But I have offset issues because of some special charcters .
here are the issues

1. when I dont perform step #3 , there are offset issues right from
   record 1. hence I included step #3
2. even when I perform step #3 , the first few thounsands of records seem to be formatted(or read ) by the AbstractLineReader correctly unless it encounters a special character (not sure but thats my assumption).

Code snippet:

```
ArrayList<AbstractLine> lines = new ArrayList<AbstractLine>();
        InputStream copyStream;
        InputStream fis;
        try {
            copyStream = new FileInputStream(new File(copybookfile));

            String filec = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(datafile));
            System.out.println("initial len: "+filec.length());
            filec=filec.replaceAll("\r", "");
            filec=filec.replaceAll("\n", "");
            System.out.println("initial len: "+filec.length());

            fis= new ByteArrayInputStream(filec.getBytes());

            CobolIoProvider ioProvider = CobolIoProvider.getInstance();
            AbstractLineReader reader = ioProvider.newIOBuilder(copyStream, "REQUEST",
                    Convert.FMT_MAINFRAME).newReader(fis);
            AbstractLine line;
            while ((line = reader.read()) != null) {
                lines.add(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

What am I missing here ? is there an additional preprocessing that I need to do for the file transferred from mainframe ?

Comment: If you have a text file, what are the "special characters" you are talking about? Can you include the COBOL record layout, and a sample of the data which causes issues?

Comment: The layout and data are proprietary and hence I will try to explain what I found out so far. I was able to figureout which field was causing the issue. In Mainframe, the field is defined as X(24) and is used to store MQ message id. this field is spaces for most records. But in a record where it is not spaces, that is when the formatting goes wrong. So though step 3(explained in my question) is required for making the records to be continuous, this causes this side affect too .

Comment: The 'Side effect' which I suspect is that this MQ message id field has either `\r` or `\n` and this gets replaced because of my step 3

Comment: This also leads to another question. When I transfer the file from mainframe using apache commons `FTPClient`, is there an option to transfer without the charcters "\n" and "\r"

Comment: If the proprietary layout you're referring to is the MQMD, that's [documented by IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q097390_.htm).  Note the documentation for the content of the message ID field.

Comment: I didn't mean the MQMD. I am referring to the cobol layout that I am using. The MQMD is stored in one of the fields in my layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a Text File (no binary data) with \r\n line delimiters try:

```
    ArrayList<AbstractLine> lines = new ArrayList<AbstractLine>();
    InputStream copyStream;
    InputStream fis;
    try {
        copyStream = new FileInputStream(new File(copybookfile));

        AbstractLineReader reader = CobolIoProvider.getInstance() 
            .newIOBuilder(copyStream, "REQUEST", ICopybookDialects.FMT_MAINFRAME)
                .setFileOrganization(Constants.IO_STANDARD_TEXT_FILE)
            .newReader(datafile);
        AbstractLine line;
        while ((line = reader.read()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Note:** The **setFileOrganization** tells JRecord *what type of file it is*. So **.setFileOrganization(Constants.IO_STANDARD_TEXT_FILE)** tells JRecord it is a Text file with \n or \r\n end-of-line markers. Here is a [Description of FileOrganisation in JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/p/jrecord/wiki/File%20Organisation/).

The **special charcters** worry me though, if there is a \n in the 'Data' it will be treated as an **end-of-line**. You may need to do binary transfer and keep the RDW (Record-Descriptor-Word) if it is a VB file.

If The file contains **Binary** data, you will need:

- do a binary transfer (with RDW if it is a VB file)
- use the appropriate File-Organisation
- Specify Ebcdic (**.setFont("cp037")** tells JRecord is US-Ebcdic)

---

I will add a second answer for *Generating Code* using the **RecordEditor**

---

If you are absolutely sure all the records are the same length you can use the low-level routines to do the reading see the ReadAqtrans.java program in https://sourceforge.net/p/jrecord/discussion/678634/thread/4b00fed4/

basically you would do:

```
    ICobolIOBuilder iobuilder = CobolIoProvider.getInstance()
            .newIOBuilder("copybookFileName", ICopybookDialects.FMT_MAINFRAME)
                    .setFont("CP037")
                    .setFileOrganization(Constants.IO_FIXED_LENGTH);
    LayoutDetail layout = iobuilder.getLayout();
    FixedLengthByteReader br 
         = new FixedLengthByteReader(layout.getMaximumRecordLength() + 2);
    br.open("...");

    byte[] bytes;
    while ((bytes = br.read()) != null) {           
        lines.add(iobuilder.newLine(bytes));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Bruce. The solution worked like a charm. How does Constants.IO_STANDARD_TEXT_FILE make the difference ?

Comment: Also I have noted yor another answer reg binary file processing

Comment: @ssdimmanuel, I have added a Wiki entry which will hopefully explain things https://sourceforge.net/p/jrecord/wiki/File%20Organisation/

Answer (score 3):

### Future Reference / Binary File

If the file does contain *Binary Data*, you really need to do a binary transfer. You may find the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) useful.

The [RecordEditor 0.98](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) has a [JRecord code Generation](http://record-editor.sourceforge.net/RecordEditorGenerate.htm#HDRJRECGEN)
function. The advantages of using the **RecordEditor Generate** function are

- The Recordeditor will try and work out the appropriate File attributes by looking at the File
- You can try out various attributes (left hand pane) and see what the file looks like with those attributes
  (right hand side).
- When happy, hit the Generate button and the **RecordEditor** will generate JRecord code. There are several *Code Templates*
  available:

  - **Standard** - will generate basic JRecord code (with a field name class
  - **lineWrapper** - will generate a "wrapper" class with the Cobol fields represented as get/set methods

#### RecordEditor Generate

In the **RecordEditor** select **Generate >>> Java~JRecord code for Cobol**

[image]

#### Generate Screen

Enter the Cobol CopyBook / Sample file and adjust the attributes as needed

[image]

#### Code Template

Next you can select the *Code Template*

[image]

#### Generated Code

Finally the **RecordEditor** will generate JRecord code based on the Attributes entered.

[image]

Comment: The auto-generated code in Writer class has a method:       private AbstractLine createFfibmf(ICobolIOBuilder iob, UserData data) throws IOException     In this method what is UserData ? Shall we create a class of this type ? I can't understand it.

Comment: The RecordEditor generates sample read and write programs which you should modify. If you do not need the write program delete it. The RecordEditor  program can not read your mind, It does not know where the data to be written to the Cobol File is coming from, you presumably do. If the source is a SQL-Fetch, you could use the ResultSet. The code is intended. The program is intended as a sample which you can modify or copy && modify. You can use it if you like.

Comment: Alternatively If the source is a DB, you could remove the  UserData data parameter and add SQL code top the method